# cloud-storage paperclip. View delay

Tags: mongoid, paperclip, google-cloud-storage

I'm using `Mongoid::Paperclip` and Fog for Google bucket with `ActiveModel::Serializers.`

Uploading of images is successful.

When I need to view object (with image) I have delay several seconds (4-15) on request (GET /object).

After caching object view, I have no any delay.

The question: **Is it delay - connection to Google API on authentication or is it Google API limits on trial period?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I'm **changed** image hosting.